# Combining GetPropertyName + multiple params function (params keyword)

Tags: c#, parameters

I have a function defined like this:

```
public static string GetPropertyName<T>(Expression<Func<T>> memberExpression)
{
    MemberExpression expressionBody = (MemberExpression)memberExpression.Body;
    return expressionBody.Member.Name;
}
```

This function returns the name of the parameter it receives.

GetPropertyName(() => SomeParameter) --> Returns the string "SomeParameter"

My problem is combining this with multiple parameters functions.

Take this function:

```
public static string NameOfFirstEmptyParam(params string[] parameters)
{
    foreach (string p in parameters)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(p))
            return GetPropertyName<String>(() => p)
    }

    return null;
}
```

As you can imagine, if we do this:

```
string param0 = "0";
string param1 = "1";
string param2 = null;

NameOfFirstEmptyParam(param0, param1, param2);
```

The function returns "p".

I would like to get "param2" instead. Any suggestion or hint?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: The syntax for `params` isn't an accident/coincidence. The calling code has to construct an array and pass that as the *single* parameter called `parameters` here. Inside `NameOfFirstEmptyParam`, you only ever receive that one parameter. Any names that were used to identify variables that were used as part of *populating* the array that was passed to you are not in any way "in scope" of the `NameOfFirstEmptyParam` method.

Comment: Like @Damien_The_Unbeliever explained, at runtime there is no `paramX` anywhere, these are equivalent to writing `NameOfFirstEmptyParam(new string[] {"0", "1", null});`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you could do something like that

```
public static string NameOfFirstEmptyParam<T>(T parameters) where T: class
    {
        var propertyInfos = typeof(T).GetProperties();
        for (var i = 0; i < propertyInfos.Length; i++)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyInfos[i].GetMethod.Invoke(parameters, null)?.ToString()))
                return propertyInfos[i].Name;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

and to execute

```
string param0 = "1";
string param1 = "2";
string param2 = null;
NameOfFirstEmptyParam(new {param0, param1, param2}); //"param2" will be returned
```

Comment: You're welcome :) .FYI  I just changed now the propertyInfos.Count() to propertyInfos.Length.